# Database and tables backup and restore

Tags: postgresql, talend

So I have the requirement of taking backup of Database (in the form of file, maybe .tar file) from one server and restoring the database to other server, also for few tables - these are two scenarios. How can I achieve this in Talend?

Is there a way i can achieve this using tSystem, tFTPconnection components ?

Comment: You use `pg_dump` and `pg_restore`.